# Why doesn't my program recognize it when I press keys in background?

Tags: python

I wrote a little silly program to play a song whenever F12 is pressed, but when I'm not in the CMD itslef it doesn't realize when I press F12, and if I try to use it as .pyw it doesn't do anything at all. Here's the code:

```
from msvcrt import getch
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024
CHEEKI = r"my directory"
breeki = wave.open(CHEEKI, "rb")
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(breeki.getsampwidth()),
                channels=breeki.getnchannels(),
                rate=breeki.getframerate(),
                output=True)
data = breeki.readframes(chunk)

while True:
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 224:
        while data != '':
            stream.write(data)
            data = breeki.readframes(chunk)
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: When you press a key, the operating system receives that key and decides what to do with it. Generally, what it does is pass that value along to whatever application is currently in the foreground. It's possible to set up global shortcuts, but just calling `getch()` doesn't have that effect. It will only read keys that are typed into the command prompt where you are running the code.

Comment: If you are developing on Windows, you can use the windows API to bind a global key event. It's not exactly a single line of code, though, and I've never tried it in Python. If this is something you want to pursue you might want to investigate IronPython.

Comment: Thank you both, and I use both C# and Python, so I am familiar with IronPython. If you have any guide or video tutorial about this subject, for any language, I would appreciate it if you left a link to it down here in the comments. Again, thank you for the quick answer!